# VarClear выполняется слишком долго в отладчике

Tags: delphi

Сделал простой пример для теста

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stopwatch: TStopwatch;
  Arr: Variant;
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  Arr:=VarArrayCreate([1, 10000, 1, 30], varVariant);
  for i:=1 to 10000 do
    for j:=1 to 30 do
      Arr[i, j]:='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

  Stopwatch:=TStopwatch.StartNew;
  try
    VarClear(Arr);
  finally
    Stopwatch.Stop;
  end;

  ShowMessage(Stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString);
end;
```

На моем компьютере в отладчике вызов VarClear занимает 15 секунд, а без него всего 0,04 секунды. Не понимаю из-за чего такая колоссальная разница. И можно ли как-то ускорить все это дело?

Comment: из вотчей снимите все что есть и проверьте. да  в целом принципиально ли сколько оно при отладке выполняется? главное чтобы само отдельно работало быстро. у меня когда то в отладчике расчет, который обычно считался 6 минут, выполнялся 5 часов.

Comment: Вотчлист пуст. К сожалению для меня, это принципиально, так как отладка невозможна с такими тормозами.

Comment: ну локальные то, наверное, всегда показываются? попробуйте перенести переменную в глобальную область видимости на уровень модуля, или приватный член класса формы, и проверить.

Comment: А если попробовать заменить на V := Unassigned;

Comment: Глобальная или локальная переменная - без разницы, время то же самое. Присвоение Unassigned - это аналогичная конструкция, VarClear вызывается в любом случае.

Comment: а вам точно нужны варианты? или точно надо их удалять в дебаге?

Comment: Нужен именно вариантный массив. Проект сложнее, здесь просто пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: интересная нелинейность. если заполнять массив не до 10к а то 1к значений, то выполняется за 110-150мсек, против 20-21 секунд у меня. без дебага 5 и 35мсек

Comment: цикл по присваиванию `unassigned` на четверть быстрее. а без дебага на четверть дольше :)

Comment: Если поэлементно присваиваете `unassigned`, то после этого нужно сделать `Arr:=unassigned`. Таким образом у меня время не поменялось.

Comment: дак очищать то в дебаге этот массив обязательно?  если очистка при отладке не принципиальна, то заверните в `{$IFNDEF DEBUG} VarClear(Arr); {$ENDIF}`

Comment: Если не очищать, то просто не хватит памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел такое решение: если запустить программу без отладчика, а потом подключиться через **Run->Attach to Process...**, то потери времени не будет, и код под отладчиком будет выполняться так же быстро, как и без него. Однако, причина такого поведения остается непонятной.